# How to set the pixmap and text to Qlabel by using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Here i want to add Pixmap and text to QLabel,by using listdir i got the my filenames but the filenames are merging in loop, so can anyone please help me how to place the my filenames in QLabel.Please help me thank you in advance.

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        pos = QtCore.QPoint(100, 100)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        s = iter(os.listdir("/home/cioc/Documents/pos/images"))
        # file1 = next(s)
        painter.drawText(pos,"vegitables")#here in place of vegitables i want to print the my filenames
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(168, 34, 3))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        url = '/home/cioc/Documents/pos/images'
        highlight_dir = url

        self.scroll_area = QtGui.QScrollArea()

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(content_widget)

        self.files_it = iter([os.path.join(highlight_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(highlight_dir)])
        try:
            for row in range(3):
                for column in range(3):
                    file = next(self.files_it)
                    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
                    self.label = MyLabel()
                    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                    self.layout.addWidget(self.label,row,column)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setGeometry(500,300,800,400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be inside the text? or do you want the image to be below the text?

Comment: okay, I guess you want me to be in the center of the image. I am right? On the other hand, do you only want 9 images or do you want all the images to be shown in 3 columns?

Comment: Do you want the amount of column to be variable depending on the width of the window?

Comment: You already confused me, you want there to be 3 rows and how many columns?

Comment: From the text it is clear to me, now let's go with numbers, let's say there are 40 images. How many rows and columns should there be?

Comment: 40 images means i want to display the 14 rows and 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the text and pixmap properties can not coexist since when one is established the previous one is eliminated. So a possible solution is to save in a new attribute.

For this case I will use QDirIterator to obtain the files, and a QTimer to load the images a little since if you have many images there will be a delay in the sample of the application or a freezing of it.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(168, 34, 3))
        painter.drawText(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.my_text)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        highlight_dir = '/home/cioc/Documents/pos/images'
        scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(scrollArea)
        content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        self._layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(content_widget)
        self._it = QtCore.QDirIterator(highlight_dir)
        self._row, self._col = 0, 0
        QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=10, timeout=self.load_image).start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def load_image(self):
        if self._it.hasNext():
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self._it.next())
            if not pixmap.isNull():
                label = MyLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.my_text = self._it.fileName()
                label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                self._layout.addWidget(label, self._row, self._col)
                self._col += 1      
                if self._col == 3:
                    self._row += 1
                    self._col = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Update:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def load_image(self):
    if self._it.hasNext():
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self._it.next())
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            label_pixmap = QtGui.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, pixmap=pixmap)
            label_text = QtGui.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, text=self._it.fileName())
            vlay.addWidget(label_pixmap)
            vlay.addWidget(label_text)
            vlay.addStretch()
            self._layout.addLayout(vlay, self._row, self._col)
            self._col += 1      
            if self._col == 3:
                self._row += 1
                self._col = 0
```

Comment: sir thank you so much and can i know the another method  image to be below the text?